# saving inputs on variable on python

Tags: python

im trying to save an input on a list and when the function is running its checking if the letter is on the list, if it is a new guess its return True. but i dont sucess to save the guesses in the variable. thanks for help !
(im even ask from the function to print the list to show if its save the guesses but its not)

```
  letter_guessed = input("please guess a letter").lower()    
  old_letters_guessed = [ ]

def check_valid_input(letter_guessed, old_letters_guessed):
    """
    this function will check if the the guess is ok
    :param letter_guesses: the user's guess
    :type letter_guesses: str
    :return: True if the guess is complies with the rules and False if not
    :rtype: bool
    """
    import string 
    if letter_guessed.isalpha() and len(letter_guessed) == 1 and letter_guessed not in old_letters_guessed :
        return(True) 
    else:
        return(False) 
    old_letters_guessed.append(letter_guessed)
    print(old_letters_guessed)
    
check_valid_input(letter_guessed, old_letters_guessed)
```

Comment: `return` stops the execution of the function and `return`s a value. Your function never makes it past that point.

Comment: replace your if clause wiht `return_val = letter_guessed.isalpha() and len(letter_guessed) == 1 and letter_guessed not in old_letters_guessed` and add a `return return_val` afther your print statement

Answer (score 0):

You have  return statement in both *clauses* of the if/else - the function returns before `old_letters_guessed.append(...` is executed. You need to move the append statement before the return statements.

Here is one way to do it.

```
is_valid = (letter_guessed.isalpha()) and (len(letter_guessed) == 1) and (letter_guessed not in old_letters_guessed)
if is_valid: old_letters_guessed.append(letter_guessed)
return is_valid
```

Answer (score -1):

You are returning the function in the if else statement itself. Any code after the return won't work.

```
letter_guessed = input("please guess a letter").lower()    
old_letters_guessed = [ ]

def check_valid_input(letter_guessed, old_letters_guessed):
    """
    this function will check if the the guess is ok
    :param letter_guesses: the user's guess
    :type letter_guesses: str
    :return: True if the guess is complies with the rules and False if not
    :rtype: bool
    """
    import string 
    if letter_guessed.isalpha() and len(letter_guessed) == 1 and letter_guessed not in old_letters_guessed :
        old_letters_guessed.append(letter_guessed)
        print(old_letters_guessed)
        return(True) 
    else:
        print(old_letters_guessed)
        return(False) 
   
    
check_valid_input(letter_guessed, old_letters_guessed)
```

This should work.

Comment: it always show false because you apend the guess to the list before checking if he is found there before

Comment: Could you explain why you define a new local variable with `old_letters_guessed = []`? There seems to be no reason for it. In fact it seems to be wrong.

Comment: yes i will explain. i want to save all the guesses of the user, so i use a new variable to do this job. without this variable i cant to save the past guesses.

Comment: But you only add one guess to this list with `old_letters_guessed.append(letter_guessed)` just to print it in `print(old_letters_guessed)`. Then after the function ends `old_letters_guessed` is thrown away. You don't save all the guesses.

Comment: you are right. how can i save this guesses ?

Comment: @shalevhaba I didn't correct the code now it should work without fail. the guesses will be automatically saved to the `old_letters_guessed` inside the function since the result will be stored to the passed argument (pass by ref.) if you change the variable name inside the function to any, it still should work.